# Adding key:value items to a dictionay in python with a for

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

Hi i have this function:

```
     def company_runtime(company_name):
        for well in all_wells:
            well_runtime = {}
            if well["groupName"].lower() == company_name.lower():
                well_runtime.update({well["name"]: well["efficiency"]})
            return well_runtime
```

And i want to get a dictionary with "names" and "efficiency" from the loop, if i enter a compay name as a parameter.

I am getting only the last element of the all_wells list that meet that condition.

what i am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The answer solves your problem, but you should also just use `well_runtime[well["name"]] = well["efficiency"]` instead of using `well_runtime.update(...)`

Comment: also the return is not where it should be, the return should be outside the for, because this will cause it to return just the first and exit the function

Comment: Thanks! moving the variable outside the loop and moving the return did it

Answer (score 5):

Each time you go through the loop you are resetting the Dictionary to `{}` or empty thus it clears it out until the last time on exit. Move `well_runtime = {}` outside of the loop.